# Copy all of the required dlls to folder

Tags: c#, .net, dll, xamarin.android

I have a MonoAndroid10 project and it has a lot of dependencies(NuGet packages too). I would like to be able to copy all of the DLL dependencies to the output folder.

Normally in a .Net Standard 2.0 project the following

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

would make that possible. But in the MonoAndroid project, nothing happens. 
If what I posted above doesn't work for a MonoAndroid project, how could I copy everything that I need in some folder, preferably in a post-build action?

I'm trying to do this because after copying all of the required DLLs in one folder I can merge them together with **ILRepack**.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this today, solved by adding

```
<CopyNuGetImplementations>true</CopyNuGetImplementations>
```

to android project .csproj file (under the desired `PropertyGroup` section).

Note: there is no need to set `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` to ture neither in android project nor in any of the dependencies.